# Как отображать все необходимые числа после ввода - C++

Tags: c++

Здравстуйте. Недавно прошло ВПР по информатике и у меня возникла проблема - числа при условии должны были отображаться(если кратно 3 и остаток 4) после ввода всех необходимых чисел, но у меня получилось так - я вводил число и оно у меня отображалось сразу(если было верно). Как решить проблему
Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int chislo = { 0 };
int minChislo = { 0 };
int maxChislo = { 1000 };
int scolkoChislo = { 1 };
int colichestwoIspolzovanyh = { 0 };
int colichestvopravilnyh = { 0 };

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Укажите количество чисел(по умолчанию 1)";
    cin >> scolkoChislo;
    if (scolkoChislo > maxChislo)
    {
        cout << "Числа не должны превышать 1000 шт. Перезапустите программу";
    }
    else
    {
        while (colichestwoIspolzovanyh < scolkoChislo)
        {
            cout << "Введите число" << endl;
            cin >> chislo;
            if (chislo % 3 == 0)
            {
                if (chislo % 10 == 4)
                {
                    cout << chislo <<" - Верно"<<endl;
                    colichestvopravilnyh++;
                }
            }
            colichestwoIspolzovanyh++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Перепишите условие понятней и дайте индескирумый заголовок вопросу

Comment: Что значит индескируемый заголовок вопросу?

Comment: Такой, чтобы можно было найти по нему ваш вопрос. См. [ask]

Comment: такого числа не существует, чтобы при делении на 3 получить остаток 4

Comment: Вот само задание - Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет количество чисел, кратных 3 и оканчивающих на 4. Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, кратное 3 и оканчивающееся на 4. Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа не превышают 30 000. Программа должна вывести количество чисел и сами числа

Comment: 24 число таковым является

Comment: Вы написали в вопросе "*если кратно 3 и остаток 4*", а не "оканчивается на 4". Исправьте вопрос!

Comment: Вам нужно объявить массив достаточного размера и заносить вводимые числа (если они удовлетворяют условию) в него. После ввода всех чисел печатайте количество чисел в массиве и в цикле все заполненные элементы массива.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что я должен создавать 1000 массивов?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выводить на консоль позже, нужно хранить данные где то. Можно хранить в массиве, в очереди, в каком то контейнере или в буфере другого потока, например в строковом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    //нужно все делать так, как требует задание
    int x{}, count{}, size{}, m;
    std::cin >> m;    
    const int 
        max{ 30000 },
        maxsize{ 1000 };
    if (m <= max) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        while (m-- && std::cin >> x && count <= maxsize) {
            if (x % 10 == 4 && x % 3 == 0) {                   
                stream << x << ' ';
                //пробел для разделения чисел
                ++count;
            }
        }
        std::cout << '\n' << "количество таких чисел:\n"
            << count << "\nсами числа:\n";            
        while (stream >> x) {
            std::cout << x << ",  ";
        }
    } else
    std::cerr << "вы задали некорректное количество чисел ";     
    return 0;
}
```